# How to improve SQL query by selecting row

Tags: c#, sql-server

I would like to improve my SQL query by selecting ROW

When I use

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT user FROM users";
```

in my code, I have an error in line

```
FillComboBox(dr["user"].ToString());
```

> Column user does not belong to the table.

Original code, which works

```
public void ReadUsersInfo(string connectionString)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM users";

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        FillComboBox(dr["user"].ToString());
    }

    Console.Read();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: _Column user does not belong to the table_ This seems a pretty clear error message to me.

Comment: Can you show your table structure? It seems the table users does not have a column named 'user'.

Comment: Without the table structure from SQL, this question is not complete. Please review 
[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't have to do much with the error. It's a pretty straightforward error that the column 'user' does not belong to your table 'users'. First thing you would want to check is, if it does. Try with a simple 'select * from tablename'. Or you can also check from the schema view if you can access the database.

Comment: Wait, does ExecuteNonQuery returns anything?

Comment: https://ctrlv.cz/mTNA

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery does not returns anything

Comment: The error couldn't be any clearer.  "COLUMN USER DOES NOT BELONG TO THE TABLE".  How else can we explain it to you?  Do you have column `user` in your table `users`??

Comment: @Eric ctrlv.cz/mTNA Yes

Comment: @SonDy Shouldn't you use `ExecuteReader()` instead?  `ExecuteNonQuery()` returns nothing.  That's why you can't find the column `user`.

Comment: `user` is a SQL Server keyword that needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`user`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/user-transact-sql) is a keyword that returns the database user name of the current user.  For example, `select user` on my database returns `dbo`.

The query below selects this context as a column without a name:

```
SELECT user FROM users

(No column name)
================
dbo
```

To return a column that has the same name as a keyword, you will need to escape it with brackets:

```
SELECT [user] FROM users
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are executing unnecessary commands. When using data adapter:

- you do not need to open connection before;
- or even create a command;
- or neither execute the command.

Second, check if you are passing the right connection string - ensure you are connecting to the database of the image, not some other that has the table 'users' but not the column 'user'.

Third, and last, based on your image the table and column exists, so the code below has to work.

```cs
public static void ReadUsersInfo(string connectionString)
{
    const string query = "select [user] from dbo.users";

    using (var dataTable = new DataTable())
    {
        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlConnection))
            {
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            }
        }

        foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dr["user"].ToString());
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: I would like to improve my SQL query. "select * from dbo.users" to select user from dbo.users